# What's the difference between transmission-daemon and service transmission-daemon?

Tags: command-line, services, bittorrent, transmission

I have an Ubuntu Server machine, which I access via SSH.
I want to use it to handle my torrents from any device and have them stored somewhere steadily.
Today I took the first step and installed the transmission package, along with the daemon, cli, etc..

So I was testing the basic functionality, and I noticed that the command `transmission-daemon + options` behaved differently from the command `service transmission-daemon + options`. Particularly, the first did not accept a straight `start` option, for example.

So, in order not to confuse myself before proceeding, and since this could help me more generally, I would like to have an informative and understandable description of what I should be aware of with regards to services and daemons, how are they implemented, roughly, and any information that could help me handle the transmission daemon, in particular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`transmission-daemon` by itself is a direct invocation of the program `/usr/bin/transmission-daemon`. This directly accepts options, but is not the correct way of running the daemon - it will run as yourself and hence exit when you log off.

`service transmission-daemon` refers to a script `/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon`. This script checks for a running instance of `transmission-daemon` when starting/restarting etc, and runs the daemon as a specific user (also called `transmission-daemon`). This is also the mechanism that will automatically launch the daemon at startup, if enabled.

You shouldn't edit this script to add options, but rather the daemon's configuration file - `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json`. See the transmission website for an explanation of the options. Note that you'll need to stop transmission-daemon (`sudo service transmission-daemon stop`) before making changes, otherwise the daemon will overwrite the settings with the ones it is currently using when it exits.

Comment: Thank you a lot. This will do in helping me understand the issue :D

Comment: That's a nice explanation.  With systemd under Ubuntu 18.04, the invocation is `systemctl start transmission-daemon` and the user is debian-transmission.  Is there any reason I wouldn't be able to log into the rpc interface as another user?  It's not accepting my uname/password when I try.